# A Counting Problem Relating to Algorithms and Divisibility

Tags: algorithms, divisibility

I find myself unable to find a fast algorithm to count a formula quickly. Can somebody tell me how to better solve it? Here is the formula mentioned above:

$$\sum_{a=1}^{m-1} \sum_{c=1}^{n-1}\left[\dfrac{cm-ac}{an-cm}\in\Bbb{Z}^+\right]$$

Note here the symbol $[x]$ means if $x$ is true then it is regarded as $1$, otherwise it is $0$.

Now $n$ and $m$ are known to us.

I have tried many ways to transform that formula, but never found a good way to make it easier to count. Sad :(

I would be obliged if you can tell me the efficient way to count it. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: the formula in the denominator is not $cn−cm$ but $an−cm$. Really sorry about that. @JeanMarie

Comment: Have you tried calculating it for some values of $m,n$ and looking for patterns (or looking up the resulting numbers at oeis.org)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tried to look for patterns at oeis.org with fixed $n$ or $m$. It seems only when $n=2$ or $m=2$, the pattern is "-1 + number of odd divisors of n". With the growth of $n$ and $m$, there seems to be no more to be found. However, it is amazing that when I fix $n$ and $m$, they show me a great symmetry. I don't know whether the symmetry helps...

Comment: If you mean there's symmetry between $m$ and $n$, that's no surprise, since $${cm-ac\over an-cm}+1={an-ac\over an-cm}$$